# Azure Media Services Live Streaming/On-Demand

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I got started using Azure Media Services for a proof of concept that I am doing for a streaming solution. Things are going great in the sense that I am using SDK's to create channels and starting and stopping these channels. I am now in the phase of actually testing the streaming functionality where some problem came into play.

What I need to achieve is sort of a Live event with video on demand afterwards solution through the SDK's in the sense that:

1. You can watch the stream while it is live.
2. You can watch the video afterwords after the event has ended. (the same channel will have multiple events and on demand archived videos).

Before actually worrying about creating the live event and starting the stream through the SDK's, I wanted to test the streaming using the channel which I created and started via the SDK's. I managed to create the channel using the SDK's with the following options:

```
{
    "aad_tenant_domain": "my_tenant_id",
    "rest_api_endpoint": "my_rest_api_endpoint_url",
    "storage_key": "my_storage_key",
    "app_client_id": "app_client_id",
    "app_client_secret": "app_client_secret",
    "live_stream_channel_name": "TestChannel",
    "live_stream_channel_description": "Test Channel Live Stream",
    "live_stream_encoding_type": "None",
    "live_stream_streaming_protocol": "RTMP",
    "live_stream_start_channel": false
}
```

I then started the channel manually in the portal, and created a default live event by clicking the "Go-Live" button in the portal. I managed to use Wirecast to stream video and I could view the live stream in the preview player in the portal as well as using the preview url in the Azure Media Player at http://ampdemo.azureedge.net/azuremediaplayer.html

I then stopped the stream in WireCast 3 minutes later, as well as the channel. Under the Live Events section in the channel I can still see the default live event that was created and when I open it, I can see a streaming locator url with a red exclamation mark next to it. It has been published but when I use this locator in the Azure media player, I get the following error:

```
A network error caused the video download to fail part-way
```

The play button on the live event is also greyed out.

I can see the asset in the assets list with 6 files which of one is a video/mp4 file of around 50MB.

Am I missing some important step such as having to encode the video during streaming instead of specifying none for encoding type when creating the channel? Could this be the reason why I cannot view my video on demand after the live stream has ended?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was the encoding settings. By following the below article and replicating all the settings, all functionality worked as expected. I could also access the video on demand even after the channel was stopped which is exactly what I wanted.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-configure-wirecast-live-encoder